# Loading multiple CSS Styles into one Using PHP Includes

Tags: php, css, include

Would loading multiple CSS files into one via PHP pose any unforeseen problems with performance or anything else.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php" type="text/css" />
```

Then the file style.php would contain:

```
<?php 

$dir = 'css/';
$dir = glob($dir.'*.{css}', GLOB_BRACE);

header("Content-type: text/css");

foreach($dir as $include){

    include($include); ?>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to do that. Why not instead just use the PHP loop to add a new link for each stylesheet in the document head, or use the @import rule in one CSS file to import them all?

Comment: @Coop combining the files into one is a good practice when you are developing for mobile by reducing the number of calls to the server for each resource.

Comment: @cmorrissey yes but compiling is usually done in preprocessing. If it has to be done live, the `@import` rule will do the job.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use this in a production environment, it would be better to concat the files and min them using your favorite minimizer

Comment: Plus with this simple approach you would probably not get any caching at all – which would make overall performance of this even worse. So implementing proper caching headers is necessary here.

Comment: Though you can be forgiven for not realising it, this is a huge question that could be answered with many pages of discussion. Web frameworks often minify and concatenate all the site's CSS and serve it as one file, which can be fetched on first arriving on the site and then cached forever until changed. This requires including version numbers in your CSS URLs to allow you to manually tell the browser when it needs to fetch a new CSS file. However, the one-huge-file approach is not the only one, and there are tradeoffs to be made between minimising requests and minimising wasted data transfer.